# c++ : meaning of keyword "typename" in this function

Tags: c++, typename

In [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/126452/66373) answer from [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/126395/c-multi-function-memoizator-and-multi-type-container) question the author posted this code:

```
 template <typename... Ts>
    typename std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<Ts...> >::type // or decltype(auto) 
        callFunction(Ts&&... ts)
    {
        using type = typename std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<Ts...> >::type;
        auto it = multiCache.find(typeid(type));
        assert(it != multiCache.end());
        auto&& fn = boost::any_cast<const std::function<type(Ts...)>&>(it->second);
        return fn(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
    }
```

The meaning of `typename std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<Ts...> >::type` is that the returned type is the same of the first element of the first element in `Ts...`, right?

Comment: Yes, this is poor-man's "index into a type parameter pack". Which is somewhat silly in this case because you might as well just write the function as taking `T&&, Ts&&...` and use `T` directly.

Answer (score 1):

No, the `typename` keyword, for all practical purposes, means the same thing as `class`.

The difference is slightly semantic. In the context of a template function or a class, a `typename` can also be a `POD`, rather than a formally declared class. It literally means "any type, a POD or a class", loosely speaking.

That's what the keyword `typename` means in generally. In this case, this has a specific purpose:

```
typename std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<Ts...> >::type
```

This tells the compiler to expect the "type" in a `std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<Ts...> >` is also going to be `class` (or a `typedef`), as opposed to a class member.

When you have something that looks like:

```
classname::identifier
```

This can refer to either a type or a class member:

```
class X {

public:
     typedef int y;
     int z;
};
```

Here, `X::y` refers to a type, and `X::z` refers to a class member. When it comes to parsing templates, a C++ compiler will assume by default that "A::b" is going to refer to a class member, unless you stick a `typename` in front of it, in which case it'll get parsed as a type.

Comment: Hey Sam.  Few thoughts: `typename` and `class` can be used interchangeably when listing template parameters a la `template <typename A, class B>`.  *"a `typename` can also be a POD, rather than a formally declared class."* - this is equally true of `A` and `B` in my earlier example - the compiler doesn't differentiate, though some coding standards do.  *"as opposed to a class member"* / *"going to refer to a class member"*- types/`typedef`s can be class members - it would be better to contrast them with class *data* member.